# javascript osc library?

Tags: javascript, osc

Does an open sound control library exists for javascript? I cant seem to find any information on this.

Comment: In what context are you hoping to use such a thing?  That is, are you hoping to use this in a browser, or are you working with something like node.js or Rhino?

Comment: At the moment for use with Titanium SDK for iOS devices via TCP.

Comment: Take a look at what Charlie Roberts is doing with [Control](http://charlie-roberts.com/Control/): OSC music controllers written in JS.

Comment: If the question is how to get OSC support on iOS using Titanium SDK, one option is to write a custom module using the [module SDK](http://developer.appcelerator.com/doc/mobile/iphone/module_sdk). It wouldn't be too difficult to write a module that wraps [oscpack](http://www.rossbencina.com/code/oscpack).

Comment: Control Certainly looks interesting, and maybe I could give PhoneGap a try instead. I was hoping there might be some existing way, since I don't yet feel I could write a module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Web sockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) are, indeed, the best way to implement OSC in a browser - but, with lacking support, the next-best thing is a custom HTTP server. [An effort](http://automata.cc/osc-web) is underway to build one - I've not checked out the process, so have a look yourself to see if it fits your purposes.

Answer (score 13):

Implemented, client-side, in my [KievII](http://kievii.net/index.html) library. Here's a link to the [code](https://github.com/janesconference/KievII/blob/master/comm/osc.js). Works nicely with my server-side, node.js, [OSC Proxy](https://github.com/janesconference/KievII/blob/master/comm/oscproxy/oscproxy.js).

Comment: seconded. Kiev is awesome.

Comment: Great if you're building a visual instrument interface for manual audio or lighting control.

Answer (score 3):

I've recently worked on a OSC library (UMD module written in ES6) named **osc-js** for different JavaScript applications (Node.js, Electron, Chrome Apps, webpages) with address pattern matching, WebSocket-/UDP Plugins and some solutions to connect it to MaxMSP/PureData/etc.:

https://github.com/adzialocha/osc-js

Comment: Excellent utility library

Answer (score 2):

I think a JavaScript OSC library, that works in the conventional way (e.g. using a UDP or TCP transport) is not possible due to the lack of low-level networking functionality provided in current browser-based implementations of the JavaScript. Cross-domain scripting limitations would also limit the usefulness of a browser-based OSC implementation IMO.

JavaScript OSC *is* possible by using [custom XPCOM components](http://www.music.mcgill.ca/~sinclair/content/blog%3acommunication_between_xul_and_osc), but at best, such solutions are going to be browser-specific.

One possibility might be to run OSC over a higher-level protocol. OSC over JSONP springs to mind as a potential area for exploration. Something similar to the [MaxJax project](http://tirl.org/software/maxjax/), which implements OSC for the Python Twisted web server.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I wasn't really aware of what would be possible. MaxJax looks pretty interesting too.