# Can Basil.js use OSC to talk with other software?

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign, basil.js

Basil.js(basiljs.ch) uses processing like syntax to control javascript objects in Adobe's InDesign. I wonder whether there is or it is possible for Basil.js to talk with other tools through OSC. Please let me know! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

There are Sockets available in InDesign via JavaScript.

But OSC is a quite complex binary protocol so you don't want to implement it yourself. Have a go in the web if you find something for your need that is written in JavaScript.

E.g. look here:
[javascript osc library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5487147/javascript-osc-library)

I can imagine that you could then adapt it more or less easily to work in InDesign with basil.js... always a bit of a gamble. If third party libraries rely to heavily on node.js or a browser DOM then it's not easy.

Comment: Oh, and please let the basil.js team know if you made it! :)